# Pygame Becomes Unresponsive after running for a few seconds

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, backtracking, knights-tour

I'm trying to write a GUI to display the Knights Tour backtracking algorithm. I have the algorithm working but when running the GUI, it becomes unresponsive after a few seconds.

```
import pygame
import time

# Init Gui

pygame.init()


# Window Size
WIN_DIMENSION = 800

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_DIMENSION, WIN_DIMENSION))
pygame.display.set_caption("Knights Tour")


# Board Size
N = 8

TARGETMOVES = N**2

# Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (180, 0, 0)

def DisplayGui(board, final=False):

    win.fill(black)

    for i in range(N):
        ydraw = i * (WIN_DIMENSION/N)
        for n in range(N):
            xdraw = n * (WIN_DIMENSION / N)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, red, (xdraw, ydraw, WIN_DIMENSION/N, WIN_DIMENSION/N), 3)
            displayText(board[i][n], xdraw, ydraw)

    while final:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                final = False
                print("CLOSING")

    pygame.display.update()
    #time.sleep(1)


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(str(text), True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def displayText(text, xdraw, ydraw):
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 7 * N)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, font)
    TextRect.center = ((xdraw + (WIN_DIMENSION / N) / 2), (ydraw + (WIN_DIMENSION / N) / 2))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)


def checkValid(board, movx, movy):
    '''
        params:
        movx => next x move
        movy => next y move

        checks if move is valid
    '''
    if (movx >= 0 and movy >= 0 and movx < N and movy < N and board[movx][movy] == " "):
        return True
    return False


def printBoard(board):
    '''
        Prints Board
    '''
    for i in range(len(board)):
        print(board[i])


def KnightsTour():
    currx = 0
    curry = 0

    # Init board
    board = [[" " for i in range(N)] for i in range(N)]

    xmoves = [-2, -2, -1, -1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
    ymoves = [1, -1, 2, -2, 2, -2, 1, -1]

    totalmoves = 1

    board[0][0] = 0
    DisplayGui(board)

    if generateMove(board, currx, curry, totalmoves, xmoves, ymoves):
        printBoard(board)
        DisplayGui(board, True)
    else: print("Invalid")





def generateMove(board, currx, curry, totalmoves, xmoves, ymoves):
    if totalmoves == TARGETMOVES:
        return True

    print("X: {} <> Y: {}".format(currx, curry)) # draw  board here

    DisplayGui(board)        


    for i in range(8):

        nextx = currx + xmoves[i]
        nexty = curry + ymoves[i]

        if checkValid(board, nextx, nexty):
            board[nextx][nexty] = totalmoves


            if generateMove(board, nextx, nexty, totalmoves+1, xmoves, ymoves):

                return True
            # backtracking
            board[nextx][nexty] = " "

    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KnightsTour()
```

I tried to slow it down using sys.sleep() but that didn't help it. I have no idea whats causing the GUI to freeze. The algo still runs in the background.

Comment: Can you toss different `print()` statements in your different loops to narrow down what the program is doing when the GUI becomes unresponsive?

Comment: I agree with what @Hoog says, you should try debugging by adding prints throughout, but also I cannot find anything obviously wrong. Possibly you keep initializing and launching the window?

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I suspect the GUI is locking up because the code "starves" the pygame event queue, never calling `pygame.event.get()` because `final` passed to `DisplayGUI()` (which handles events) is not true until the last move(?).  All that said, I ran it for some minutes, and it did not lock up for me.  I think you should try to re-factor the looping such that events are checked on every display update, and window-close is properly handled somehow.  Maybe run the algorithm in a sub-thread, and post update events to a main loop for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to overcome this problem without changing your code significantly you can call [pygame.event.pump(](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump)) in your `DisplayGui()` function. This will make your operating system / window manager believe that your program hasn't frozen.

```
def DisplayGui(board, final=False):

    win.fill(black)
    if not final:
        pygame.event.pump()
    for i in range(N):
        ...
```

It would be more helpful to actually handle QUIT events so you could end the program prematurely without ending the python process.

If you're considering reorganising your code, perhaps this [openbook](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/pygame.html) would be useful. This section describes a standard game loop which should look something like:

event handling → update state → draw new state → update display